# Intellij, target JRE vesion doesn't match project jdk version

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Community version 2019.3 on my MacBook. I have a simple springboot (java) project. Whenever I run my unit test I get the following warning:

[image]

Where should I check on Intellij to get rid of this error? (I heard on internet "Project Settings", but I can't find where this option is)

Comment: I'm using the ultimate edition 2019.3.3, for work, and there Menue "File", Project structure". In this opening dialog under "Plattform Settings" there is an entry called "SDKs".

Comment: Project JDK: File | Project Structure | Project -> **Project SDK**. The Other JDK (Target JRE) is taken from the Run/Debug Configuration you run from the module or JRE that is specified there. It must be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are building for target version of Java `1.8`

Depending what you are using, Maven or Gradle, you set the target version of java with:

**Gradle**

```
  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
  targetCompatibility = '1.8'
```

Docs:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java-extension
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/JavaVersion.html

**Maven**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Docs:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

You can change this version to `12` or `JavaVersion.VERSION_12` to use your build JDK, but then you would lose the compatibility and won't be able to run the application jar with Java 1.8.

You can also change the build SDK version, on **macOS** press `command + ;` and go to *Project Settings -> Project* and change the Project SDK to the one you want to build it with.

Comment: I also had to update the Platform Settings.  On Mac:  File > Project Structure > Platform Settings/SDKs > remove all but the "1.8" folder (and in my case "Kotlin SDK" folder).  I had to delete a 15.0.2 folder that IntelliJ had added automatically.

Comment: @wildcat12 yes, that can happen when the versions are different the other way round. The `target` version always must be equal or up to the version of your project SDK and the `source` version must be equal or up to the `target` version.
`SDK` >= `target` >= `source`

Answer (score 64):

The **target JRE version** for Gradle can be configured from within Intellij via the `Gradle JVM` setting at `Preferences (cmd + ,)` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Gradle`:

[image: Gradle JVM Setting]

The **project JDK version** can be configured from the `Project SDK` setting in `Project Structure (cmd + ;)`:

[image: Project SDK setting]

(Screenshots taken from IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4)

Comment: Note: You may need to restart IntelliJ IDEA for the changes to take effect

Comment: This worked for me, but you may also need to click on "Reload All Gradle projects", from Gradle tool window.

Comment: Project SDK is gone in IntelliJ 2022.1.4

Answer (score 5):

Intellij + Gradle also refers to the Gradle JVM setup within Intellij.

Ensure to change that as shown below:
[image]